# redis lua debugger does not step over

Tags: lua, redis

Running this command:

> /usr/bin/redis-stable/src/redis-cli --ldb --eval test.lua

The debugger starts at the first line and does nothing more.
I can not type **s** or **step** to step over.

There is a screenshot:
[redis debugger stucked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkFF0.png)

I am using redis 3.2.8 .

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What is the full text of the script you are running? Is it possible that your script is running an infinite loop?

Comment: My script does have two lines of code, only.
local foo = redis.call('ping')
return foo

Comment: Interessting. I tried it now with Ubuntu Server 16.10 and the default redis-server installation out of the package list (3.2.1). It works. I don't know why it does not run in my Debian machine.